# how can we change responseType in firebase.functions().httpsCallable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Initially i was using http post method like below to generate pdf

```
this.httpClient.post(this.globals.constUrl + 'reportData', data, {responseType: 'blob'})
```

access code with subscribe the response

```
const myBlob: Blob = new Blob([res], {type: 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8'}); // replace the type by whatever type
```

is your response

```
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        window.open(fileURL);
```

The above code is working fine but now i want to get it done with httpsCallable, while attempting this I am not able to change responseType as we do in post method, so PDF is not being generated
Please suggest a way to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Callable type functions can only send data formatted as JSON.  If you need to send something different, you shouldn't use a callable at all.  Use a normal [HTTP type function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to gain full control over the response.